# Disk check lasts >14 minutes -> interrupted by bootup daemon -> restarts at next reboot

Tags: fsck, boot

I am running the latest ubuntu (xenial in apt/source.list). When the computer starts it has to check a fairly large disk. A typical check lasts about 2 hours.

So... as scheduled the computer boots and starts the disk check. After 14 minutes some bootup daemon gives a message that fsck has been running for a long time. It does give a counter that starts at 14 minutes, counting upwards. That same counter also say that there is no limit for the fsck  process. Yet when the counter reaches 14 minutes 30 seconds, it kills fsck and continues with booting as if everything went fine.

Next bootup... exactly the same.

Is there any way that I can tell that bootup daemon that a long running fsck is okay ?

Comment: Maybe related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upstart/+bug/1504688).

Comment: It might be, or might not be. Using the fastboot oiption does not really solve the problem because the filesystem check is simply skipped. More interesting is that if I umount that particular filesystem (telinit 1; umount filesystem) and then try to run an e2fsck it tells me the device is still in use, allthough it is not listed in the output of a mount command at all.